# Optionally saving selectively data in one-go only when you want it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where data does not initially exist until an action is taken that stores all settings made by client in one-go. To illustrate this simply, a button click that stores all column values off a (HTML) table into a database table (let's call this `dbo.Settings`).

So instead of inserting into this `dbo.Settings` all the default values prior to user making any changes to their individual settings (ever), I kind of created the pseudo data for them that will be returned whenever requested, kind of like `SELECT`-ing the default values:

```
SELECT 
    CanView = ISNULL(CanView, 1),
    CanRead = ISNULL(CanRead, 1),
    CanWrite = ISNULL(CanWrite, 0)
FROM 
    dbo.Settings AS s
WHERE
    UserId = @id
```

Rather than doing:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Settings WHERE UserId = @id)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Settings (UserId, CanView, CanRead, CanWrite)
    VALUES (@id, 1, 1, 0)
END
```

The problem with this is whenever I need to add a new setting column in the future, I now have to note one more procedure to modify/add the default value for this column as well -- which I don't like. Using `TRIGGER` would be an option but I wonder what the best practice in managing data like this would be. Or would you do something like this:

```
CREATE PROC Settings_CreateOrModify
    @userId INT,
    @canView BIT = NULL,
    @canRead BIT = NULL,
    @canWrite BIT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Settings WHERE UserId = @userId) BEGIN
        UPDATE s
        SET
            CanView = @canView,
            CanRead = @canRead,
            CanWrite = @canWrite
        FROM
            dbo.Settings AS s
        WHERE
            s.UserId = @userId AND
            (@canView IS NULL OR @canView <> s.CanView) AND
            (@canRead IS NULL OR @canRead <> s.CanRead) AND
            (@canWrite IS NULL OR @canWrite <> s.CanWrite)
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO 
            dbo.Settings(UserId, CanView, CanRead, CanWrite)
        SELECT
            @userId, @canView, @canRead, @canWrite
    END
END
```

How would you handle data structure like this? Any recommendation or correction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, what is exact question? Looks like you already built your sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SP is a good way to go, and doing it like this is commonly called an "UPSERT".

It also looks to me as if the block:

```
        (@canView IS NULL OR @canView <> s.CanView) AND
        (@canRead IS NULL OR @canRead <> s.CanRead) AND
        (@canWrite IS NULL OR @canWrite <> s.CanWrite)
```

is problematic since it causes the UPDATE to run only if ALL parameters changed their value. I don't think that's what you wanted to say. Just SET the three values regardless of what's already there.

You still end up with three places to change when you add a new setting: The Table, the Upsert and the Defaults.

---

One very different approach is this:

1. Apply the defaults to the columns in the table definition.
2. Whenever you need the values for a new user, do: `INSERT INTO dbo.Settings(UserId)` The defaults will fill the rest of the columns.
3. Now you can retrieve the values for ALL users (new or not) in the same way from the table.
4. Since you already inserted the user in step 2, you know the userid is there already and you can always save the changes via a simple update.

This eliminates the SP and the need of providing the defaults in one extra place.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and for introducing UPSERT! I think I'll go with your very different approach. :)